# Blackberry 9300: Can't locate installed application

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I have a Blackberry 9300. I install an application over the air but I cannot see the app anywhere. The app runs the first time after the installation. And if I go to options /applications I can see it there installed. However the icon app is nowhere to be found, and I can't run it again.

The app that I'm testing is the 2.0 Cordova example for blackberry.

Thanks

Comment: The title was reworded. Pls explain how's "off topic" the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check out in the downloads folder?